# Galaxy Note 3 - Is there a way to add more apps to use when drawing a 'Pen Window'?

Tags: samsung-touchwiz, samsung-galaxy-note-3, s-pen

Is there a way to add more applications in the list that appears when you press the button on the S-Pen and select "Pen Window" to draw a floating application?

It would be really nice if you could open a floating twitter or Facebook application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without root it is up to the developer of the particular application, and chances are there aren't enough Note 3s out there to justify it.

There is an [S-Pen SDK from Samsung](http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/sdk)

There are lists (but these will often be out of date in no time)  [like this best S-Pen apps](http://www.phonearena.com/news/The-best-S-Pen-apps-for-the-Samsung-Galaxy-Note-3-II-Neo-8.0-10.1-and-NotePRO_id39527?utm_source=feedburner) out there.

---

With root access  [there is a way to open any app in Pen Window Mode](http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-open-any-app-in-Pen-Window-mode-on-the-Galaxy-Note-3_id48340)

> First, make sure you are rooted with busybox installed.
>
> Second, make a backup.
>
> Third, just download [PenWindowManager_v1.apk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?s=3af476de9cbb1f18fa1d774505d25605&attachmentid=2301626&d=1380904970)  and install as normal.
> Finally, just tick the apps you want and don't forget to press the save button. A soft reboot maybe required for the changes to take effect.